# How to change MUI table sort label icon color

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styling

I am trying to change the table sort label icon color from default gray to red but I am unsure how to do so. Does anyone have any recommendations?
Here is my code:

```
<TableSortLabel
    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
    onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
    IconComponent={ArrowDropUpIcon}
    sx={{ fill: "green" }}
>
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the icon color, you need the following sx value:

```
<TableSortLabel
    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
    onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
    IconComponent={ArrowDropUpIcon}
    sx={{
        '& .MuiTableSortLabel-icon': {
            color: 'green !important',
        },
    }}
>
```

The classname to override comes from the [TableSortLabel API docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-sort-label/) or by inspecting the element and looking for an element class name with the pattern `Mui[Component name]-[name of the slot]`

See the MUI doc on [how to customize](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) for more information